# How to define the what() function in derived class from exception class in C++?

Tags: c++

In this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;

class myexception : public exception
{
     virtual const char* what() const throw()  //<---**** Stared statement.
    {
     return "My exception happened";
    }
};
```

What does the *stared* statement mean. What is the reason for using **const** keyword and the type **char*** ?

I am confused with both of the const keywords. I know the basic use of const like declaring a variable that will store a unchangeable value.....sort of like #define but when it is used with functions (such as in parameters) it is confusing. I am confused on the usage of char* instead of char in this line. Also what is the purpose of specifying `const` before `throw()`?

Comment: Maybe you can expand your question with what you found confusing with the explanation in your C++ reference?

Comment: First of all, *which* of the two `const` keywords do you mean? Secondly, you do know about function return values?

Comment: I am confused with both of the `const` keywords. I know the basic use of `const` like declaring a variable that will store a unchangeable value.....sort of like `#define` but when it is used with functions (such as in parameters) it is confusing. Yes, I know about function return values....I am confused on the usage of `char*` instead of `char` in this line.

Comment: I think you need to [find a good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and start reading. It will tell you all you need about what the asterisk means in different places (hint: look for a chapter on *pointers*).

Comment: I know the * means your are creating a pointer `int *a = &b;` and also that it is also a dereferencing operator. So, what my doubt is whether the return value in the above code is of type `char` or `char*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Update] Since the author is asking more questions, I'll update the answer with both parts.

First of all, this function is an override function of `std::exception::what()`, the base function is defined that way, so the overrided version has to be the same syntax.

Then let's split the statement into two parts.

1. The return value `const char*`
2. The part after `what() const throw()`

First, check the return statement `return "My exception happened";`, it's returning a const c-like string, the type is `const char*`, so the return value is defined that way.

Second, the `const` after `what()` indicates it's a const function that will not modify any member (except for `mutable` though) of the class.
The `throw()` means it never throws.

Comment: Why does it have to be `char*` and not `char`? What difference will be caused? Also, what is the reason of specifying `throw()`....is it so that the function cannot throw an exception? Furthermore, what is the reason for specifying `const` in `const throw()` ?

Comment: Probably you should ask these questions in the question, since it's only asking the `const char*` part in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

The const char* mean that the caller to what() will receive a string and will not be able to change the string (the char that the pointer is pointing to).
This is an overriding of std::exception::what() so you can return a new explanation to your own exception (this is why you must return const char*, the original method does too)

Comment: So if the type was only `char`, I would not be able to return a whole string of characters?

Comment: a char would mean passing 1 char by value. char* tells that somewhere there is a consecutive set of chars in the memory representing a string, and the char* is pointing to it. This is known as a c-style string (because that's how to pass strings in c)